# wget on Centos 7 Terminal how to download only text without website style code

Tags: centos, text-processing, wget, html

```
sudo wget -O /home/KrypticRelic/Desktop/DefaultAccess.txt  phenoelit.org/dpl/dpl.html
```

This prints out a significant amount of padding for the actual text that I'd like.

Ex.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html><head><title>Default Password List</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#000000" link=#FF6600   vlink=#CC6600 alink=#FFFF00 text=#FF9900 >
<CENTER><H1>Default Password List</H1><h2>2007-07-03 </h2>

<TABLE FRAME=VOID CELLSPACING=0 COLS=47 RULES=NONE BORDER=0>
    <COLGROUP><COL WIDTH=177><COL WIDTH=348><COL WIDTH=472><COL WIDTH=292><COL WIDTH=150><COL WIDTH=399><COL WIDTH=429><COL WIDTH=841><COL WIDTH=34><COL WIDTH=94><COL WIDTH=66><COL WIDTH=208><COL WIDTH=48><COL WIDTH=48><COL WIDTH=45><COL WIDTH=51><COL WIDTH=86><COL WIDTH=34><COL WIDTH=79><COL WIDTH=71><COL WIDTH=208><COL WIDTH=48><COL WIDTH=41><COL WIDTH=41><COL WIDTH=40><COL WIDTH=86><COL WIDTH=34><COL WIDTH=59><COL WIDTH=66><COL WIDTH=208><COL WIDTH=48><COL WIDTH=48><COL WIDTH=65><COL WIDTH=40><COL WIDTH=86><COL WIDTH=34><COL WIDTH=74><COL WIDTH=171><COL WIDTH=86><COL WIDTH=45><COL WIDTH=48><COL WIDTH=48><COL WIDTH=51><COL WIDTH=119><COL WIDTH=28><COL WIDTH=64><COL WIDTH=71></COLGROUP>
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD WIDTH=177 HEIGHT=17 ALIGN=LEFT>Vendor</TD>
            <TD WIDTH=348 ALIGN=LEFT>Model</TD>
            <TD WIDTH=472 ALIGN=LEFT>Version</TD>
            <TD WIDTH=292 ALIGN=LEFT>Access Type</TD>
            <TD WIDTH=150 ALIGN=LEFT>Username</TD>
            <TD WIDTH=399 ALIGN=LEFT>PASSWORD</TD>
            <TD WIDTH=429 ALIGN=LEFT>Privileges</TD>
            <TD WIDTH=841 ALIGN=LEFT>Notes</TD>
```

How do I remove the HTML and keep the lists? The site is provided above so you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: Does e command work differently without the `sudo`? A small piece of general advice is not to use ``sudo`` unless you need to.

Comment: Thanks, just starting out but I remember that as a rule of thumb - appreciate the refresher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download with html removed, use `links` (or `lynx`) with the `-dump` option:

```
links -dump http://website.web
```

Or:

```
lynx -dump http://website.web
```

The two differ in output style.  For one, `lynx` will format hyperrefs while `links` will ignore them.

#### Installation

On a debian/ubuntu-like system, either program can be installed with `apt-get`:

```
apt-get install links

apt-get install lynx
```

Comment: The links function works and does exactly what I asked. The Lynx, however, does the same as wget. I tried both but removed Lynx since I have wget. Appreciate the quick response.

Comment: @TimothyW.Times I'm glad that `links -dump` works for you.  I'm surprised about `lynx -dump` as I use it frequently for this purpose but maybe you have a different version or patch level.  In any event, `links` produces less formatting in the output and that sounds like what you prefer anyway.